# Resources for Non-Bayesian Online Change-point Detection

Tags: change-point, online-algorithms, structural-change

I am interested in learning about the fundamentals of on-line change point detection. I am specifically not interested in the Bayesian methods.

The only solid resource / review / survey I could find for on-line methods was the book *[Sequential Analysis: Hypothesis Testing
and Changepoint Detection by Tartakovsky, Nikiforov, and Basseville](https://www.amazon.ca/Sequential-Analysis-Hypothesis-Changepoint-Detection/dp/1439838208)* but it is very advanced. Are there any other resources out there for someone getting into this line of research at an early grad level?

An example for what I am looking for, [this paper that surveys offline methods is amazingly clear and beginner friendly](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00718).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Chapter 2 of [Dean Bodenham's PhD Thesis](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/24484/1/Bodenham-D-2014-PhD-Thesis.pdf) to be a good introduction to the subject.

One of the measures defined therein is the CUSUM process, which gives a sequence $S_0, S_1, \dots$ that becomes very large when the sequence $x_1, x_{2}, \dots$ is consistently exceeding the mean $\mu$ (taking into account the variance of the sequence $\sigma^2$). There is a different definition for the CUSUM that is more useful  than the one given in Section 2.1.4 (Bodenham uses this definition in [a different paper](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/34625/2/main_continuousmonitoring.pdf)):
$$S_0 = 0,$$
$$S_j = \max(0, S_{j-1} + (x_j - \mu) / \sigma - k), \ \ \ \ j = \{1,2,\dots\}.$$
You would declare that a change has occurred once the process $S_t$ exceeds some threshold $h$. In the paper I mentioned, Bodenham sets $S_0 = \mu$, which I think is a mistake: if $\mu > h$ then we would trigger the end of the process immediately.

In addition to the CUSUM that checks for positive drift in the process $x_1, x_2, \dots$, you can also run a simultaneous CUSUM process $T_0, T_1, \dots$ given by
$$T_0 = 0,$$
$$T_j = \max(0, T_{j-1} - (x_j - \mu) / \sigma - k), \ \ \ \ j = \{1,2,\dots\},$$
which gets large when the process $x_1, x_2, \dots$ is consistently below the mean.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I hadn't come across those and they do seem well-written. I'll accept your answer but if you ever come across more / different references that are as helpful. Please add them or notify me. Cheers.